# How to exclude and format matching values in NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, dictionary, object

I have an `Object` `obj` as below:

```
const obj = {
Hostname: "abc.com"
Check1Status: "PASS"
Check2Status: "PASS"
Check3Status: "FAIL"
Check3ErrorHeading: "Reason for Check3"
Check3ErrorDetail: "Details for Check3"
Check4Status: "FAIL"
Check4ErrorHeading: "Reason for Check4"
Check4ErrorDetail: "Details for Check4"
TotalExecutions: 5
};
```

1. I want to capture `TotalExecutions`
2. I want to exclude all the key value pairs which have `PASS`
   as the value.
3. I want to exclude the key `Hostname` and it value.
4. I only want to capture the `checks` which have `Status` as `FAIL`
   such that the output looks as below:
   `TotalExecutions:5,Check3:Reason for Check3:Details for Check3, Check4:Reason for Check4:Details for Check4`

The final output should be a `string`.
I have written the following code which is excluding `PASS` and including `TotalExecutions` and excluding `HostName` but not implementing `4`

```
            const result = Object.values(obj).map
            (el => Object.entries(el).filter(([key, value]) => value !== 'PASS' && key !== 'Hostname').reduce((acc, [key, value]) => ({
                ...acc,
                [key]: value
            }), {}));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const obj = {
  Hostname: "abc.com",
  Check1Status: "PASS",
  Check2Status: "PASS",
  Check3Status: "FAIL",
  Check3ErrorHeading: "Reason for Check3",
  Check3ErrorDetail: "Details for Check3",
  Check4Status: "FAIL",
  Check4ErrorHeading: "Reason for Check4",
  Check4ErrorDetail: "Details for Check4",
  TotalExecutions: 5
};

var output = [`Total Executions: ${obj.TotalExecutions}`];

for (var key in obj) {
  if(obj[key] === 'FAIL') {
    output.push(`
    ${key.replace('Status', '')}: 
    ${obj[key.replace('Status', 'ErrorHeading')]}: 
    ${obj[key.replace('Status', 'ErrorDetail')]}`)
  }
}

console.log(output.join(', '))
```

Answer (score 1):

The following should work for You.

```
const obj = {
    Hostname: "abc.com",
    Check1Status: "PASS",
    Check2Status: "PASS",
    Check3Status: "FAIL",
    Check3ErrorHeading: "Reason for Check3",
    Check3ErrorDetail: "Details for Check3",
    Check4Status: "FAIL",
    Check4ErrorHeading: "Reason for Check4",
    Check4ErrorDetail: "Details for Check4",
    TotalExecutions: 5
};

let resultObj = {};

for (let prop in obj) {
    if (prop == "TotalExecutions") {
        resultObj[prop] = obj[prop];
    }

    if (obj[prop] == "FAIL") {
        let startOfKey = prop.replace("Status", "");
        resultObj[startOfKey] = obj[startOfKey + "ErrorHeading"] + ":" + obj[startOfKey + "ErrorDetail"]
    }

}
console.log(resultObj)
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope it can help you

```js
function formatter() {
  const obj = {
    Hostname: "abc.com",
    Check1Status: "PASS",
    Check2Status: "PASS",
    Check3Status: "FAIL",
    Check3ErrorHeading: "Reason for Check3",
    Check3ErrorDetail: "Details for Check3",
    Check4Status: "FAIL",
    Check4ErrorHeading: "Reason for Check4",
    Check4ErrorDetail: "Details for Check4",
    TotalExecutions: 5
  };

  let result = `TotalExecutions:${obj['TotalExecutions']}`;

  Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => {

    if (obj[key] === 'FAIL') {
      const checkKey = key.match(/Check\d/);
      const errorHeading = obj[`${checkKey}ErrorHeading`];
      const errorDetail = obj[`${checkKey}ErrorDetail`];
      result += `,${checkKey}:${errorHeading}:${errorDetail}`;
    }
  });

  return result;
}

console.log(formatter());
```